# Rewrite rules not working on nginx

Tags: php, nginx, php-5.5

I have the following rewrite rules in sites-available/myapp.conf. My setup is Nginx, php5-fpm.

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

            # also tried
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;

    }
            # also tried
            # replacing last with break

            rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$" "/index.php?lang=$1" last;
            rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$" "/index.php?lang=$1&page=$2" last;

    location ~ \.php {

            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_nam$
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;

            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

I have also tried wrapping the rewrite rules in a @rewrite block but no success.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    #rewrite rules
}
```

Passing the variables manually does work

```
index.php?lang=en&page=pageName&type=typeName
```

Can someone please help solve this. Spend the entire night already but no luck.

Comment: Could you explain what kind of incorrect behavior is happening when you load a URL?

Comment: @Dan Getz There is no incorrect behaviour or anything in the logs. The rewrite rules just do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem to be that fpm processes were still active or the following problem caused the error:

```
2016/06/03 02:06:24 [emerg] 6604#6604: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2016/06/03 02:06:24 [emerg] 6604#6604: still could not bind()
```

I restarted nginx after each change with success but the rewrite rules would not work. Using

```
sudo fuser -k 80/tcp
```

solved the problem. Hope this is useful for someone else.

Where:

fuser - identify processes using files or sockets

-k     Kill  processes accessing the file.

(src: http://geektechinfo.blogspot.nl/2013/09/starting-nginx-nginx-emerg-bind-to.html)

If fuser does not work, try killing all active nginx processes:

```
sudo killall -KILL nginx
```

And (re)start nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```